# What is the Big-O time complexity of Java's Stream.max()?

Tags: java, java-stream, time-complexity, max, big-o

There are lots of questions about Big-O complexity of Java's Stream, Stream.sorted(), etc. But I haven't found one from Java's Stream.max().

It doesn't seem to have been answered on StackOverflow. I also can't seem to find an answer on Google. Maybe I am searching in the wrong place. Perhaps it is possible to look into Java's implementation of max to find out about this? In any case, I'm rather new in the Java world and would be very grateful for an answer and even a discussion.

Comment: That has probably not been asked because it is as trivial as it gets. It obviously is O(n), because what else could it possibly be!?!

Comment: O(n) obviously? You have to go through every element to find max/min.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with java, much less java streams. Any language/tool/situation will be O(n) if any modicum of thought at all has gone into the implementation.

Comment: As with all these questions about time complexity of Stream operations, it ignores the fact that Streams work with arbitrary sources whose iteration costs we can’t predict. As said by others, each element has to be evaluated, hence, it can never be better than O(n), but since the big O notation denotes the *worst case*, we can’t say anything without knowing the source, as well as the actual comparison implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's going though all the elements once, keeping track of what's the largest so far. This means that it's linear in the number of elements assuming the comparison is constant.